# margins and alignment changes while and after sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

```js
$('.parent').sortable({
  axis: 'x',
  containment: "parent",
  tolerance: 'pointer',
  helper: "clone"
});
```

```css
.parent {
  text-align: justify;
  text-align-last: justify;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  margin: 14px auto;
  background: gold;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: cell;
  padding: 5px 9px;
  background: lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>lorem ipsum lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem ipsum lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem ipsum lorem</div>
</div>
```

Two problems:

- Margins, i.e. `parent` height changes while dragging.
- There is no `align:justify` after pasting an item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery script appears to remove `inline-block` on the items, randomly, and when it does your `text-align: justify;` will have no effect.

If you use `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;` it will work much better.

Stack snippet

```js
$('.parent').sortable({
  axis: 'x',
  containment: "parent",
  tolerance: 'pointer',
  helper: "clone"
});
```

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  margin: 14px auto;
  background: gold;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  position: relative;
  cursor: cell;
  padding: 5px 9px;
  background: lightseagreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child'>lorem ipsum lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem ipsum lorem</div>
  <div class='child'>lorem ipsum lorem</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this is a good solution, but not the correct diagnosis --  the divs are still displaying as in-line blocks after drag.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Keep on dragging them, randomly, one after the other, and they will do that.

Comment: @MarkMeyer If you use OP's snippet and first drag the middle to left and drop it, and then again, and again, and again..., do the same, you'll see that will happen....and I use Chrome

Comment: Hmm. Can't reproduce it. I see the space changing between them but the divs are staying inline for me. And my inspector shows them as inline also. Not sure why it's different.

Comment: @MarkMeyer If the space changed, then right click and _Inspect_ the rendered result and you'll find it, though they are still _inline_. And if they all were `inline-block`, they would _justify_ and have an equal space between.